# Liquidity seeking algorithms open source implementation

Tags: market-microstructure, algorithmic-trading, liquidity, order-execution

Are there any free online liquidity seeking algorithms? Possible an open source implementation? Not looking for anything state-of-the-art, but just to get an idea how they work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the paper [Optimal split of orders across liquidity pools: a stochastic algorithm approach (2011)](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/090780596) we present the theoretical aspect of liquidity seeking, thus you will learn how they work.

There is a seminal (once again) [white paper by Robert Almgren on iceberg chasing](http://www.streambase.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/StreamBase_White_Paper_Smart_Order_Routing_low.pdf) that is very informative too.

Answer (score 1):

I can't post comments yet, so I will put it here. The second link to the answer above does not work. Can anyone provide the reference to the iceberg chasing paper by Almgren?

Comment: http://complexevents.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/streambase_whitepaper_smart_order_routing.pdf